# Django gives a long error after trying to runserver with crispy-forms added in the project

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I used pipenv to install crispy forms into my project, and also added it into my settings.py file under my list of installed apps. When I try to run the server after adding this in, I get a long error message from Django. If I take out crispy-forms in the installed app, the server will run.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'crispy_forms',
)
```

I get a long error message with the `LookUp error: No installed app with label 'admin'` at the bottom. Due to the excessive amount of errors, Stack Overflow will not allow me to post the full error list.

Comment: make sure all the migrations are done.

Answer (score 0):

Try `python manage.py check` in the terminal. It will give you a proper error.

Comment: I now get the error msg "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy-formsusers'"

Comment: `pip install django-crispy-forms` have you installed a library ?